# Similar to n+1 with two models in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This has probably been answered before but I have been searching a lot and can only find solutions for the "regular" n+1 problem. I have two models, regions and colors, regions can have several colors and a color is associated with a region. Say there are 10 regions and 5 colors for each region, 50 rows in the color table. I want to find all the colors, with a specific color_mode, for the regions.

```
create_table :region do |t|
  t.string :name
end

create_table :colors do |t|
  t.references :region, index: true
  t.integer :color_mode
  t.column :color, :bigint
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :colors
end
```

I can get the job done with:

```
  @ids = [] 
  @colors = []
  Regions.all.each do |region|
    @ids.push(region.id)
    @colors.push(Color.find_by(region: region, color_mode: some_color).color)
  end
```

But this will produce n+1 queries, and I can't really figure out how to do it more efficient.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you can just use `Color.select('color').where(color_mode: some_color).group('region_id')`

Answer (score 0):

I would have a third model added.  To me you should probably have the ability for a color to belong to multiple regions anyway.

```
class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :region_colors
  has_many :regions, through: :region_colors
end

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :region_colors, through: :region_colors
  has_many :colors
end

class RegionColor < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
  belongs_to :color
end
```

This way you can just do

```
@color = Color.find(params[:id])
@colors_regions = @color.regions
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ordinary n+1 query problem to me.

You just have to try solving it backwards.

```
Color.includes(:region).where(color_mode: something).find_each do |color|
  # color.region contains the corresponding region
end
```

**Note:** duplicate regions might be found if on any of the `Region`s there are multiple `Color`s associated with the same `color_mode`. If not - then you're good to go.